# what is the difference of two opencv include folders

Tags: opencv

OpenCV has two include folders: `opencv` and `opencv2`. In many cases, we include header files from `opencv2`. But what is the `opencv` folder mainly used for? 
In `opencv`, there is a `cv.h` that is also frequently used. If I just write the code as follows:

```
#include <cv.h>
```

Does that means the `cv.h` in the `opencv` folder is included? or from `opencv.h` that is located in the `opencv2` folder?  when both of the folders have been well configured and ready for use.

I also note that both of the include folders have a `highgui.h` file. What is their difference? 
If I write the code:

```
#include <highgui.h>
```

then, which one is actually included?

Comment: The `opencv` headers are legacy includes for backward compatibility. For new code, use the `opencv2` directory.

Comment: @DanMašek: what about including <cv.h>? Is <opencv2/opencv/cv.h> ok? There is no cv.hpp in the opencv2 folder

Answer (score 0):

See the post here for answers http://answers.opencv.org/question/4397/include-folder-structure-opencv-andor-opencv2/